# asciidoctor-pdf cover page image size to fill the page

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor-pdf

I'm attempting to have the book-cover.png fill the entire first page of an ebook, but with the settings below it still leaves a small margin of white on both sides. What's the best image size to fill the cover and are there any options that would fill the page and not leave white margins? Thanks!

```
= Book Title
Author
Version 1.0, 2020-03-12
:front-cover-image: image::book-cover.png[Front Cover,1050,1600]
:doctype: book
:imagesdir: images
:toc: right
:toclevels: 2
ifndef::ebook-format[:leveloffset: 1]
```

Comment: What size of page are you using? A4? US Letter?

Comment: That's a good question. Here are the settings I have in the book.adoc

:front-cover-image: image::book-cover.png[]
:doctype: book
:imagesdir: images
:toc: right
:toclevels: 2
ifndef::ebook-format[:leveloffset: 1]